# Why Visual Studio creates .exe installer files?

Tags: visual-studio, installation

when I build solutions in Visual Studio, that generates installer files as .exe and .msi, .exe files are useful for what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.EXE` file that is created by the installer project is a bootstrapper for the `.MSI` setup file. It is used to launch the `.MSI` setup file.

Generally, both will launch the setup program and allow the user to install the application. However, sometimes the `setup.exe` file will run a custom validation routine to determine if the user's computer meets the minimum requirements for installing the software.

For example, if the user does not have Windows Installer, they will not be able to launch the `.MSI` file, but the `.EXE` application will still run and inform them that they need to install Windows Installer first. For .NET applications specifically, the `.EXE` file verifies the presence of the appropriate version of the .NET Framework, and if it is not present, it prompts the user to download and install it.

You can customize the prerequisites that are required for your application in your installer project using Visual Studio. See these MSDN articles for details on how to do that:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(v=VS.100).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: On a sidenote: You cannot do the prerequesite check in the MSI itself because only one instance of msiexec is allowed to run at a given time. So if one of the prereques comes as MSI package your own program would have to terminate itself to allow the execution of the other one. Splitting the installation in two parts allows for one smooth process. Of course MS could add some yield functionality to msiexec but as it is this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Others have commented on the *how* (.exe bootstraps the .msi) but part of the reason *why* is that users know that .exe files are the things you run.  I don't think your average user knows that .msi files are something that you can click on to install an application.

Answer (score 1):

The `.exe` file is made for installing the prerequisites of your application.

Let's say your application uses the .Net 3.5 framework, you can tell the installer project to include the installation of the needed libraries if they're not already installed.

You may also deactivate it, so only the `.msi` is being created.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Prerequisites_in_Setup.aspx) page shows how to activate and configure the prerequisites setup, just uncheck the checkbox in order to deactivate it.

You also find more details on the process of [Bootstrapping on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> the capability to automatically detect
>   the existence of components during
>   installation and install a
>   predetermined set of prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

`.exe` files are useful for executing your programs that you've just built in Visual Studio, assuming you're not doing web applications.

Pretty much every Windows program out there is executed using files with an `.exe` suffix.

Comment: He is asking why the installer gets generated as an `MSI` _and_ as an `EXE`, and further, what the point of the installer as an `EXE` is.

Comment: Yes, but the .msi file already instal my build. I want to know what is the diference between the .exe and the .msi files

Comment: @Oded: you're right. Misread. Must be because it's friday. Downvote me if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Installer** exe files are normally just the msi wrapped in a bootstrapper. The bootstrapper can do anything, but normally its purpose is to ensure the user is running a sufficient version of [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688%28VS.85%29.aspx), then extract the msi and invoke `msiexec.exe` to start installing the msi. Generating installers as exe's is deprecated these days, but some still do it.